# C# database connection use of USING or not?

Tags: c#, database-connection, sql-server-ce, using-statement

I tried to find my answer on google as always but I found only a partial answer to my question.

My question is: while creating a connection to a database, what is the more preferable way to make it: without or with the `USING`.

For now, as I start in C# (but I have some skill in PHP), I learned online with the `USING` method like below:

```
string conString = Properties.Settings.Default.mattDatabaseConnectionString;

using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
{
    using (SqlCeCommand query = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM customers", con))
    {
        SqlCeDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader();
    }
}
```

On google, I found that the use of the USING prevent from forget to close the `ExecuteReader` and dispose the `SqlCeCommand`. But you can also make it without like below (example took from msdn):

```
SqlCeConnection conn = null;
        SqlCeCommand cmd = null;
        SqlCeDataReader rdr = null;
        try
        {
            // Open the connection and create a SQL command
            //
            conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = AdventureWorks.sdf");
            conn.Open();

            cmd = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM DimEmployee", conn);

            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            // Iterate through the results
            //
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                int employeeID = rdr.GetInt32(0);   // or: rdr["EmployeeKey"];
                string lastName = rdr.GetString(5); // or: rdr["FirstName"];
            }

            // Always dispose data readers and commands as soon as practicable
            //
            rdr.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();
        }
        finally
        {
            // Close the connection when no longer needed
            //
            conn.Close();
        }
```

I know the 2 methods above are equivalent but whats is the best method for skilled programmers and why. Probably the second for less characters??

And is the `SqlCeEonnection conn = null;` and the 2 others really necessary??

Thanks guys

Comment: Use whatever you find more readable. In my opinion `using` is less verbose and doesn't raise questions like _"is sqlceconnection conn = null necessary"_.

Comment: You should check `conn` for null before closing it to make these 2 methods equivalent

Comment: I'm surprised no one has mentioned the [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) interface, the `Dispose()` method, or garbage collection yet.  Granted, the question was asked about a database connection (et al), but it's as much about .Net programming as it is about Sql Server or coding style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`using` is the cleanest way to make sure your connection is disposed, and I like to write nested using statements in this way:

```
using (SqlCeConnection con = new SqlCeConnection(conString))
using (SqlCeCommand query = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM customers", con))
{
    con.Open();
    using(SqlCeDataReader reader = query.ExecuteReader())
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

The try-catch is equivalent as you mentioned.

The only exception, of course, is when you *don't* want to dispose the connection right away. For instance, you might need to use the data reader outside the `using` block, in which case you shouldn't use a `using` because it will dispose the connection when you exit it, and the data reader will throw an exception when you try to use it while the underlying connection is closed.

Comment: @TimSchmelter thanks. didn't pay attention to that.

Comment: ok yes but your first line doesnt have any { } for the USING. this mean you have to close the connection at the end exact ?

Comment: tested, love it. Its a good compromise between the 2 methods.

Answer (score 1):

Using isn't 'necessary', but it's a good idea because it'll save you some issues.

Yes if you remember to close in the `finally` then you're going to be alight, but it's less verbose to just put it within using. It also makes for cleaner code in my opinion (as you're limiting the scope of the variable to within the scope of the connection)

Comment: My opinion is the code will look more clean without the USING. Do you personally use the USING or not?

Comment: I personally do use the Using. But yeah it's mostly a stylistic choice. If you prefer using try/finally blocks then it's your decision. It's that tiny bit more verbose.

Comment: @Matt how do you define cleanness of code? More lines = more clean? `using` is very compact and self-descriptive syntax to dispose resources

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Less code mean the code is more light.. more clean. no?

Comment: @Haedrian perfect. thanks. I think I will continue use the USING to be sure to not have issues.

Comment: @Matt exactly. Less code = less code to read and understand, less code to maintain. `using` gives much less code then `try..finally`

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy ok yes I understand your point of view. The use of try-finally make more lines, but make the connection code more clean.

Use of the USING make less lines but make the connection code harder to read.

.. heh :P for me right now thats really a missing issues case. I think i'll go for the use of USING.